# Transactional Outbox and Message Duplicates With Mutiple Microservice instances

Tags: microservices, transactional-outbox

I have a Microservice that is having a Postgres database and I have some CRUD operations that I do with this service. For some of the insert operations, I need to pass on the newly inserted record to another service and I'm using a messaging system in between.

The architecture pattern is like where I run several instances of this Microservice behind a load balancer and every insert is processed by one of the running instance of the Microservice. To implement the transactional outbox, I have a table where I write the intent and I have a simple polling mechanism in the Microservice itself that polls this table every minute to fetch the intent from the outbox table and sends it to a messaging system. Now I have several questions:

1. If I run multiple instances of this Microservice, then I might end up having to select the same records by these multiple instances and this could result in duplicates, unnecessary resource utilization etc.,
2. What do I do after publishing the intent to the message broker? Should I write to the outbox table against this record that this message is now successfully sent to the message broker? This scenario sounds like my original problem where I want to write to the database and to the external system in one commit, just in this scenario the order is reversed. So where is the real benefit?

Is there any other simpler alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with distributed systems, asynchronous communications and messaging you should consider delivery guarantees which your app requires. There are basically 3 options:

- At most once
- At least once
- Exactly once

There last one (which you think you need) is considered [impossible](https://exactly-once.github.io/posts/exactly-once-delivery/) in general case (though exactly once semantics for processing can be achieved with some deduplication handling, like Kafka [does](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/)).

Most of application I've seen use/require "at least once" delivery for business messages, so the subscriber should be able do deduplicate (or handle duplicates in some other way). Basically you will want to include some unique id in message so the handler can maintain collection of processed messages and filter out duplicates.

> If I run multiple instances of this Microservice, then I might end up having to select the same records by these multiple instances and this could result in duplicates, unnecessary resource utilization etc.,

Personally I would go with just one instance of the outbox processor (i.e. separate service for it or some infrastructural magic to have only one if the service instances to perform the processing) and I would argue that this should be enough in most of the cases (still you will need to have a dedupe logic on the subscriber side but this will basically solve the issues with unnecessary resource utilization).

If you still want to process the outbox from multiple service instances then you have at least 2 options:

- Use the database for synchronization - use transaction/database provided locking (depending on the implementation you can actually have a single processor at a time). For example - [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE), send selected messages, update the processed rows, commit the transaction.
- Implement some kind of partitioning - each row is assigned to some service instance (all of them have their unique ids in some way) and every instance sends only it's own messages. Though this can be quite cumbersome to implement and will lead to message ordering issues.

TL;DR

*"Is there any other simpler alternatives?"* - yes, create a single instance dedicated service which will process the outbox. Either way assign unique message ids and implement deduplication on the subscriber side.

Comment: So a single instance dedicated service to process the outbox - You mean this will be a separate microservice single instance that will access the same database that the other microservice owns. Correct?

Comment: @joesan basically yes. But it is quite a common pattern in general to split processing and API into different applications/instances. They are deployed together (i.e. they are single deployment unit for example as single deployment consisting of different pods in k8s, so you can consider them a single microservice) but they are different applications/pods/etc.

Comment: @joesan one thing to mention - usually you will want them to share the codebase, i.e. they are in the same repo (or a service folder in case of monorepo).

Comment: Another option is using the leader election API's from Kubernetes. Is this simpler from an infrastructure perspective than having a separate service for this purpose?

Comment: @joesan sounds like a good option, one that falls under "infrastructure magic" in the answer.

Comment: But the problem with that Kubernetes leader approach is that I cannot run that locally. To be able to test that locally, I need to have a kubernetes infra in place. It simply complicates local application development.